# How would I change the src of an iframe with a text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

So, Mojang released a version of Minecraft for the browser and I've been trying to add it to my website. I successfully did that with an iframe but people wanted multiplayer. Since multiplayer works through links, the goal would be to input the link they receive from someone else and change the iframe from the standard one to the new multiplayer one.

What I've tried is to get the user input, assign it to a variable, and use document.write to rewrite the existing iframe with the new src.

Here's what I've got. Note: it's in a modal.

```css
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 300px;
}
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
.button {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div align="center"><iframe id="change" name="change" width="800" height="500" src="//classic.minecraft.net"></iframe></div>
 <div>
 <button class="button" id="button"><b>Fullscreen</b> </button>
 <button class="button" id="modal" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"><b>Multiplayer</b></button>
 </div>
 <script src="/fullscreen.js"></script>
 <script>
   function changeIframe() {
  document.write(" <iframe  id='change' name='change' src='#" + input + "' width='800'  height='500'   allowfullscreen></iframe>");
}
 </script>
 <script>   
 var input = document.getElementById("detroit");
 </script>
 <div id="id01" class="sprckn-modal">
  
<form class="modal-content animate">
    <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  
  
  <div class="sprckn-modal-content">
    <label for="link"><b>Paste Multiplayer Link Here</b></label>
    <center><input type="text" onsubmit="changeIframe()" id="detroit" placeholder="https://classic.minecraft.net/?join=somelettersand#s" name="link" required></center>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <center><button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button></center>
</form>
  </div>
</div>
`
```

Absolutely no part of the iframe changes, but my website url does, with a ?link=(linkhere). It can be better shown off at https://sprocken.com/game/minecraft/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the existing iframe source:

```
function changeIframe(url) {
  document.getElementById('change').src = url;
}
```

Use the `onchange` event instead of `onsubmit`:

```
<input type="text" id="minecraftInput" onchange="changeIframe(this.value)" id="detroit" placeholder="https://classic.minecraft.net/?join=somelettersand#s" name="link" required>
```

Comment: It was right, but it only worked the first try. It's been implemented at https://sprocken.com/game/minecraft/ if you want to see what might be wrong there

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
var url = $('#detroit').value;
$('iframe').setAttribute('src', url);
```

This will help you to add the url entered in the textbox to the iframe src. I tested it in your developer console of your website.

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7403.png)

Comment: So, the screenshot shows the link https://sprocken.com/game/minecraft/inputtext.
However, it doesn't end here. The goal is to change the iframe's link; from https://classic.minecraft.net to https://classic.minecraft.net/inputtext, not mine.
To say it easily, I want to be able to input https://classic.minecraft.net/?join=joincode and have it replace the current src in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to change the iframe source with text. By not actually changing the inner source of the iframe but by using HTML features and a simple JS variable I came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Iframe change</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
hr {
height: 5px;
background: black;
}
</style>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Youtube Unblocker</h1>
<center><input type="text" id="embedlink"><button 
id="submit">Submit</button>
<br>
<hr>
<center><xhtml id="iframe"></xhtml></center>
<hr>
<h2 style="text-align:center;">Previously Watched</h2>
<script>
let embed = "";
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){
embed = document.getElementById('embedlink').value;
document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = embed;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```