# entering input causing link change

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

This sort of links back to a previous question that I made. The goal was to change the iframe src with a text input. After lots of experimentation, it worked. However, this has arisen a new problem. After I enter the link and submit it, it adds /?link=linkhere to the end of the page and refreshes it. Then, once it's refreshed, the original src comes back, making it useless.
Here's the most important code:

```
 <iframe
  id="minecraftFrame"
  src="//classic.minecraft.net"
  height="500"
  width="800"
  frameborder="0"
  scrolling="no"
  allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="input">
<button class="button" onclick="changeChannel()">Go</button>
<script>   
function changeChannel(){
  document.getElementById("iFrame").src = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
}
</script>
```

I'm unsure of what to try at this point, since I'm not too experienced with javascript. I just don't want the main page to refresh after change the src.

Comment: the original post for creating the src changer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370104/how-would-i-change-the-src-of-an-iframe-with-a-text-input

Comment: `function changeChannel(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent default, i.e. stop event bubbling which is resulting in reload. See if that works for you. Seems like it should as you are submitting the form which would result in refresh of the page.

```
function changeChannel() {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Edited here: https://sprocken.com/game/minecraft
Nothing's changed. Adding the (e) into the input didn't make a difference either.

Comment: @Yonokid changed code above, and tested on your site, seems working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code included this --- document.getElementById("iFrame").src
the id of the iframe is "minecraftFrame" and not "iFrame"
or you could use document.querySelector('iFrame')

and stop the page reload with

```
  function changeChannel(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Code goes here
}
```